# Validar caracteres, mayúsculas, minúsculas y caracteres numéricos para una contraseña

Tags: javascript, regex

Mi expresión regular debe de cumplir lo siguiente:

- Debe de tener mínimo 8 caracteres,
- mínimo 2 letras mayúsculas,
- mínimo 2 letras minúsculas
- y mínimo 2 caracteres numéricos.

Buscando por internet he encontrado esta que es parecida a la mía, la cual es para validar con al menos un dígito, al menos una minúscula y al menos una mayúscula:

```
^(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[A-Z])(?=\w*[a-z])\S{8,16}$
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vendría a ser algo así:

```
^(?=(?:.*\d){2})(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2})\S{8,}$
```

Con el operador `?=` (look ahead) compruebas que:

1. Existan al menos dos dígitos `(?:.*\d){2}`
2. Existan al menos dos mayúsculas `(?:.*[A-Z]){2}`
3. Existan al menos dos minúsculas `(?:.*[a-z]){2}`

Con el cuantificador `{8,}` indicas que debe tener una longitud mínima de 8 sin límite máximo.

Comment: Qué buen truco, con este look ahead no tienes que estar pendiente de revisar todas las combinaciones (letra número letra / número letra letra, etc).

Comment: Con `\S` no permite espacios en blanco, algo que puede o no interesar, pero que no se pidió en la pregunta