# Expresion regular para contraseña javascript

Tags: javascript

hola tengo que hacer una expresión regular para una contraseña pero con unas condiciones

que la clave tenga letras (mayúsculas y minúsculas), además de por lo menos un número o un símbolo (ej, $, @, etc).

soy bastante inútil con las expresiones regulares y no me salen bien estuve buscando si encontraba alguna similar y modificiarla y tampoco me salio

intente utilizar este pero no me sirvio

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])([A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]|[^ ])+$/
```

Comment: @ArtEze ahi me gusto el problema nomas es que dice un numero O un caracter y estaba viendo desde antes como modificar para poner uno o el otro y no lo encontre tenes alguna idea?

Comment: Decir **o**, es opcionalidad, y se puede solucionar de dos formas, `[ab]`, o `(a|b)`... En este caso `a` es un número, que es `\d`, y `b` es un caracter, es decir, `[$@]`, y ahí se pueden agregar los caracteres que consideres necesario. Supongo que con armar esa expresión regular estaría solucionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la respuesta de Asier Villanueva: [Validar caracteres, mayúsculas, minúsculas y caracteres numéricos para una contraseña](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/75926/13558)

Solo hay que modificar algunas cosas.

He hecho una descomposición de la expresión regular que había en esa respuesta. Ahora las cantidades mínimas para las letras mayúsculas, minúsculas, números o símbolos, y la longitud de la contraseña están en un objeto.

También se construye la expresión regular mediante una concatenación de cadenas de caracteres (*strings*).

La parte que dice `(?:.*\d){2}` fue cambiada por `("+número+"|["+símbolos+"])`:

- `número` es `"\\d"`, y esto se convierte a `\d`, ya que para mostrar una barra invertida se necesitan dos.
- `símbolos` es `$@`, y se pueden agregar todos los que se deseen.

```js
var cantidades={
  números_o_símbolos:1,
  mayúsculas:1,
  minúsculas:1,
  letras:1,
  longitud_contraseña:1
}
var número="\\d"
var símbolos="$@"
var número_o_símbolo="("+número+"|["+símbolos+"])"
var números_o_símbolos="(?:.*"+número_o_símbolo+"){"+cantidades.números_o_símbolos+"}"
var mayúsculas="(?:.*[A-Z]){"+cantidades.mayúsculas+"}"
var minúsculas="(?:.*[a-z]){"+cantidades.minúsculas+"}"
var cadena="^"+
  "(?="+números_o_símbolos+")"+
  "(?="+mayúsculas+")"+
  "(?="+minúsculas+")"+
  "\\S{"+cantidades.longitud_contraseña+",}"+
  "$"
console.log(cadena)
var expresión_regular=new RegExp(cadena,"g")

var pruebas=[
  "contraseña",
  "contraseñaCONTRASEÑA",
  "contraseñaCONTRASEÑAnúm3r0s",
  "contraseñaCONTRASEÑAnúmero$"
]
for(var i in pruebas)
{
  var encontrados=pruebas[i].match(expresión_regular)
  var encuentra=encontrados!=null
  console.log("La contraseña \""+pruebas[i]+"\""+
    (!encuentra?" no":"")+" es válida"
  )
}
```