# Expresión regular validar contraseña

Tags: regex, java-swing

Estoy intentando crear una expresión regular para que me valide una contraseña. He estado probando varias cosas y revisando varias preguntas de otros usuarios pero no consigo dar con la tecla, es verdad que nunca se me han dado bien este tipo de cosas.

Mi contraseña debe tener las siguientes condiciones:

- Mínimo 8 caracteres
- Alfanumérica y debe contener al menos una letra y un número.

He creado esta expresión:

```
^(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[A-Za-z])\S{8,}$
```

Pero me falla, me coge por bueno el _, y además si pongo simbolos especiales al final me los da por buenos, por ejemplo aaaaaa6& y sin embargo me los da por malos cuando los pongo entre las letras y los números.

¿Me podéis echar una mano?

edit: he estado revisando el post [Validar caracteres, mayúsculas, minúsculas y caracteres numéricos para una contraseña](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75907/validar-caracteres-may%C3%BAsculas-min%C3%BAsculas-y-caracteres-num%C3%A9ricos-para-una-contr) pero no consigo hacer que no sea obligatorio mayúsculas y minúsculas

edit2: he conseguido dar con la tecla. ^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{8,}$

Un saludo

Comment: ¿No admite espacios? ¿Se aceptan letras acentuadas?

Comment: no se admiten espacios ni letras acentuadas, la idea es que no se permita ningún tipo de carácter especial. solamente letras y números.

Comment: Al final he podido sacar la expresión regular, por si a alguien le pudiera servir la adjunto.  ^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{8,}$